# Difference between event.file and event.target.files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to use `formData` with React to store an image file and send to a backend service with Axios.

This is my component:

```
<Dragger
        ref={el}
        type="file" 
        name='file'
        multiple={true}
        onChange={(event) => {
            uploadFile(event.file)
        }}
>
    <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
        <InboxOutlined />
    </p>
    <p className="ant-upload-text">
        Click or drag file to this area to upload
    </p>
    <p className="ant-upload-hint">
        Once selected, the file will automatically be uploaded.
    </p>
</Dragger>
```

This is how I'm accessing `formData` before I send it to the API:

```
const uploadFile = file => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', file)
    // api request ...
}
```

This does not work.

I've seen other implementations where people use `event.target.files[0]`; I've tested this, and this does work.

Is there a way to make `event.file` work? Aren't `event.file` and `event.target.file[0]` the same?

Edit:

This is the source to the dragger component in ant design: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/tree/master/components/upload

Comment: Can you post the source code for `Dragger`? Or if it is part of a react library, a link to the component docs?  It is tough to help you with using the onChange function if we can't see it's signature.

Comment: @Zacx Definitely. Just edited the original post; it's a component from ant design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this component recently so I can explain how I got it working.  Instead of using `onChange` to upload your file, you can simply use the `action` prop of the Dragger component to tell it where to send the file.  Then you can use `onChange` to update your UI when the upload is complete.

```js
<Upload.Dragger
  action={'/myImageRoute'}
  beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
  accept='.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.webp'
  withCredentials={true}
  onChange={({ file }) => file.status === 'uploading' ? setLoading(true) : setLoading(false)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Synthetic Events in React

Files are actually stored on the element itself in the DOM, so to access it you must access the target of the event and then its files attribute. The [MDN docs on files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) has more information, so just access `event.target.files` and you should be able to find your file. This is assuming you're handling React's Synthetic Event.

```js
<Dragger
        ref={el}
        type="file" 
        name='file'
        multiple={true}
        onChange={(event) => {
            uploadFile(event.target.files[0])
        }}
>
```

If you are, this simple fix should make it easy enough, but if you're looking for the [React Synthetic Event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) you'll notice there's not a file property or event. You'd have to use a library(which it looks like you might be) to handle it that way, and if you are you'd want to read that library's documentation about its file property on the custom onChange interface it's using.

## The Custom Event you're handling

To me it looks like you're using [Ant Design's Dragger](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-drag) and if that's the case I'd take a closer look at their example and compare it to yours. Below I have copied their `onChange` handler for their `Dragger` example:

```js
  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  }
```

If you look at their example which I linked too, it looks like you might not be utilizing it in the way you're expecting. This is more for information. You should look at the example and at the `action` property.

```js
const props = {
  name: 'file',
  multiple: true,
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};
```

Your files should just upload to `action` if you look at the props in the example itself. Try setting that and then checking on your server to see if it's getting the file. Since it does look like you're using the Ant Design element, this should be what you're looking for.

## The Difference

Pure React would be a synthetic event, but this is a custom event that Ant Design uses, and you're not properly implementing the library. Take a close look at the example in the Custom Event and implement the `action` property to get it to upload to your server.

Comment: this may be what you eluded to in your second paragraph, but when i do that, `event.target.files` is undefined

Comment: Expanded with the onChange from Ant Designs examples